# Absolute value of a function in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Being a beginner, I'm having difficulty in plotting |sinx|. Can anyone help me with plotting
y=|sinx| in [0,2pi] and y=0 elsewhere in tikz?

Comment: Please show the code you have tried so far!

Comment: Sir I used package tikzpicture and  I couldn't proceed after \begin{tikzpicture} \end{tikzpicture}.

Comment: I suggest looking the related package `pgfplots` and its documentation.

Comment: You can try looking [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/105570/125871) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121794/125871) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148011/125871) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408241/125871) or [Google: plot function tikz](https://www.google.com/search?q=plot+function+tikz&rlz=1C5GCEM_enUS950US950&oq=plot+function+tikz&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30l9.3882j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Also, pgfplots would use `abs(sin(x))` to calculate y.  Look up Part VIII in the pgf manual  and subsection 4.4.3 in the pgfplots manual.